# Why is this function not printing out the specified objects values? C#

Tags: c#, list

Im creating a program that will be used like a library, where you can for exampel look up a spesific book.. Let me run you through the code..

The problem im trying to solve is that the lookup function does NOT print out the books in my library list that contain that letters in question

**This class is used for creating the books in the library**

```
    class Bok
    {
        public string titel;
        public string author;
        public bool loaned;

        public Bok(string titel, string author, bool loaned)
        {
            this.titel = titel;
            this.author = author;
            this.loaned = loaned;
        }
    }
```

**And with this I have created a new list, called library along with an example books**

```
            List<Bok> library = new List<Bok>() { };

            Bok book = new Bok("alex bok", "alexander", false);
```

**Now I'm letting the user input a string, which will be used to search for a specific book located in that list, im making all the cases of the string answer to lower and then checking if any object in the list library has an object of which the values "author"  or "title" contains the string that the user entered, and then prints it**

```
            void Print(Bok bok)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hej");
                Console.WriteLine($"{bok.titel}\n" +
                    $"{bok.author}\n" +
                    $"Lånad : {bok.loaned}");
            }

            void Lookup()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sök efter titel, eller författare");
                string svar = (Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();

                foreach(Bok bok in library)
                {
                    if (bok.author.Contains(svar) || bok.titel.Contains(svar))
                    {
                        Print(bok);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Boken finns inte i biblioteket.");
                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to debug your code. Set a breakpoint, step through the code line by line and examine the state at each step. You will then be able to determine exactly where and how the code doesn't behave according to your expectations. Even if you still can't solve the problem, at least you'll be able to provide us with all the relevant information.

Comment: question is not clear. Please re work on the question.

Comment: `book` is not added to `library`, so `library` is empty and no match can be found

Comment: You created a library. Then you created a book. Then you left the book lying on the pavement in the rain. While the library is warm and dry... and still empty.

Comment: Slightly OT: [string.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) has an overload where you can supply for instance `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to perform case-insensitive comparison. That does *not* ignore accents and such, however

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, note that that overload is only available in .NET Core, including .NET 5 and later. In .NET FRamework projects, you can use `String.IndexOf` instead, possibly in your own custom `Contains` extension method.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - thanks, I forgot about that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are not seeing the whole code, I'm not sure if you already did this at some point of your code, but i would try to:

1. Add the `Bok book = new Bok("alex bok", "alexander", false);` to the list `List<Bok> library = new List<Bok>();` (get rid of the {} after creating the new list, you don't need them) with `library.Add(book)`. Otherwise you iterate through an empty array in your `Lookup()` function.
2. Did you call your `Lookup()` function at some point in the code? Otherwise its just defined, but not executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is add a collection of books then match the lower cased value.

Also consider using comparison or regex for more complex searches.

This however will work.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/nBswHI